# How to find the exact word in between a sentence in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching

I am trying to replace the words in a sentence if the word exits in "words" column. The below code replaces and updates back to the table but it replaces the word which is in between a word as well. How to look just for an exact word to replace?

For ex: It replaces `testing` in `automtestingation` with it's id. I am just looking for `automtestingation 2` instead.

```
Create table temp(id NUMBER,
word VARCHAR2(1000),
Sentence VARCHAR2(2000));

insert into temp(1,'automation testing','automtestingation testing is popular kind of testing');
insert into temp(2,'testing','manual testing');
insert into temp(3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing');

merge into temp o
using (
  select s_rid, sentence, is_last from (
    select s.rowid s_rid, w.id word_id, w.word,
      cast(replace(s.sentence, w.word, w.id) as varchar2(4000)) sentence,
      length(w.word) word_length
    from temp w join temp s
    on instr(s.sentence, w.word) > 0
  )
  model
    partition by (s_rid)
    dimension by (
      row_number() over(partition by s_rid order by word_length desc, word) rn
    )
    measures(word_id, word, sentence, 0 is_last)
  rules (
    sentence[rn > 1] = replace(sentence[cv()-1], word[cv()], word_id[cv()]),
    is_last[any] = presentv(is_last[cv()+1], 0, 1)
  )
) n
on (o.rowid = n.s_rid and n.is_last = 1)
when matched then update set o.sentence = n.sentence;
```

Got this piece of code with the help of one of the fellow mates here. Thank you.

```
id word                   sentence
1  automation testing     automtestingation 2 is popular kind of 2
2  testing                3
3  manual testing         this is an old method of 2
```

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to follow. Consider providing a coherent data sample and explain what should and should not be replaced and why.

Comment: I am trying to replace the words in all the sentences if the word exits in the "words" column. For ex: id = 1 - automtestingation testing is popular kind of testing. The expected outcome is automtestingation 2 is popular kind of 2. Instead I am getting autom2ation 2 is popular kind of 2.

Comment: Assuming you can cram regex in there somewhere then word boundaries are your friend: `\b`

Comment: Yes, is there a way to add the boundaries within instr?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Oracle does not natively support `\b` word boundaries in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
Create table temp(
  id       NUMBER,
  word     VARCHAR2(1000),
  Sentence VARCHAR2(2000)
);

insert into temp
SELECT 1,'automation testing', 'automtestingation testing is popular kind of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'testing','manual testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'punctuation','automation testing,manual testing,punctuation,automanual testing-testing' FROM DUAL;
```

**Merge**:

```sql
MERGE INTO temp dst
USING (
  WITH ordered_words ( rn, id, word ) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) ASC, word DESC ),
           id,
           word
    FROM   temp
  ),
  sentences ( rid, sentence, rn ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID,
           sentence,
           COUNT(*) OVER () + 1
    FROM temp
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.rid,
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             REGEXP_REPLACE(
               s.sentence,
               '(^|[^a-z])' || w.word || '($|[^a-z])',
               '\1' || w.id || '\2',
               1,
               0,
               'i'
              ),
             '(^|[^a-z])' || w.word || '($|[^a-z])',
             '\1' || w.id || '\2',
             1,
             0,
             'i'
           ),
           s.rn - 1
    FROM   sentences s
           INNER JOIN ordered_words w
           ON ( s.rn - 1 = w.rn )
  )
  SELECT rid, sentence
  FROM   sentences
  WHERE  rn = 1
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    sentence = src.sentence;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | WORD               | SENTENCE                                
> -: | :----------------- | :---------------------------------------
>  1 | automation testing | automtestingation 2 is popular kind of 2
>  2 | testing            | 3                                       
>  3 | manual testing     | this is an old method of 2              
>  4 | punctuation        | 1,3,4,automanual 2-2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8314a21469537354e8160e7bceff439)*

---

Or you can modify your `MERGE` to use the same techniques with the `MODEL` clause:

```sql
MERGE INTO temp o
USING (
  SELECT s_rid,
         sentence,
         is_last
  FROM   (
    SELECT s.rowid AS s_rid,
           w.id    AS word_id,
           w.word,
           CAST(
             REGEXP_REPLACE(
               REGEXP_REPLACE(
                 s.sentence,
                 '(^|\W)' || w.word || '($|\W)',
                 '\1' || w.id || '\2'
               ),
               '(^|\W)' || w.word || '($|\W)',
               '\1' || w.id || '\2'
             )
             as varchar2(4000)
           ) sentence,
           length(w.word) word_length
    FROM   temp w
           JOIN temp s
           ON REGEXP_LIKE(
             s.sentence,
             '(^|\W)' || w.word || '(\W|$)'
           )
  )
  model
    partition by (s_rid)
    dimension by (
      row_number() over(partition by s_rid order by word_length desc, word) rn
    )
    measures(word_id, word, sentence, 0 is_last)
  rules (
    sentence[rn > 1] = REGEXP_REPLACE(
                         REGEXP_REPLACE(
                           sentence[cv()-1],
                           '(^|\W)' || word[cv()] || '($|\W)',
                           '\1' || word_id[cv()] || '\2'
                         ),
                         '(^|\W)' || word[cv()] || '($|\W)',
                         '\1' || word_id[cv()] || '\2'
                       ),
    is_last[any] = presentv(is_last[cv()+1], 0, 1)
  )
) n
on (o.rowid = n.s_rid and n.is_last = 1)
when matched then update set o.sentence = n.sentence;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e949576d357c042fbb76f19ea1e5495c)*

Comment: Your approach works. Thank you. But there is a situation here. 
I have inserted 2 more rows B-number analysis and B-number analysis table. 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=427f9c00b41e6cae35e5b42930c3d178
And the value to be replaced is http://localhost/"id"/<u>"word"<u>
If you see the value for id = 5 (B-number analysis) the sentence is http://localhost/6/<u>http://localhost/5/<u>B-number analysis<u> table<u>
But the actual value is supposed to be http://localhost/6/<u>B-number analysis table<u>

Comment: @Ana That is because you have completely changed the meaning of your question by adding in a second part to it, which does not appear in your original question, where the replacement includes the text you are replacing and why it is important to ask the right question. The query works for the situation you described in the question; we can't give you answers for questions you haven't asked. If you want to ask a follow on question then please ask it in a new question rather than trying to significantly change the scope of the existing question in comments.

Comment: I get it. I will post a new question but your answers did help me. Thank you so much. Hope to get help from you on my new question.

Comment: I have posted the question : 57884379. If possible please look into it. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Starting point:

```
SQL> select * from temp;

 ID WORD                 SENTENCE
--- -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
  1 automation testing   automtestingation testing is popular kind of testing
  2 testing              manual testing
  3 manual testing       this is an old method of testing

SQL>
```

Now,

- do the self join
- check whether *word* exists (`instr`) in the *sentence*
- if so, replace it with its `ID`

Here's the query:

```
SQL> merge into temp t
  2    using (with
  3           test as
  4             (select a.id aid, a.sentence, b.word, b.id bid,
  5                     instr(a.sentence, b.word) ins
  6              from temp a join temp b on a.id <> b.id
  7             )
  8           select aid, sentence, word,
  9             regexp_replace(sentence,
 10                            '(^|\s|\W)' || word ||'($|\s|\W)',
 11                            case when ins = 1 then to_char(bid)
 12                                 else ' '||bid||' '
 13                            end) result
 14           from test
 15           where ins > 0
 16          ) x
 17  on (x.aid = t.id)
 18  when matched then update set t.sentence = x.result;

3 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from temp;

 ID WORD                 SENTENCE
--- -------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
  1 automation testing   automtestingation 2 is popular kind of 2
  2 testing              3
  3 manual testing       this is an old method of 2

SQL>
```

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=df5e538704fdd193c4115747c93ac1b4) gives `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables` when there are multiple words in the same sentence.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=adafbd3077de943a6db5a190d583de4a) it also doesn't match all the words in the sentence `testing testing testing` (and strips the white spaces).